# Overloading operators : const vs non-const return type : any difference of performance?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, operator-overloading

If we go to the wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++) about C++ operators, we have as an example :

```
Addition : a + b -> T T::operator +(const T& b) const;
```

So the operator return a **non-const** of type T.
If we look at this [guideline](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html) the author say that the return type should be a **const** to avoid the following syntax :

```
(a+b) = c
```

Now assume that this syntax doesn't bother me, and consider that a and b are large arrays. From a "pure" performance point of view, can the absence of the const keyword in the return type prevent optimizations from the compiler (g++ and intel icpc with -O3) ? And if the aswer is "yes", why ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an interesting question. In C++03, there would be no better chances to optimize with either of the two options and it would be a matter of style choice (I myself don't believe on the whole return by `const` to avoid unlikely errors).

In C++11, on the other hand, it might actually have an impact. In particular, if your type supports move operations, and the copy/move out of the returned value cannot be elided, then by returning by `const` you are effectively disabling moves <sup>*</sup>

```
// T is move assignable, with the usual declaration of a move assignment operator
T f();
const T g();
int main() {
   T t;
   t = f();     // can move
   t = g();     // cannot move!!!
}
```

In your particular case, it depends on what *large arrays* means for you, if they are `std::array` (or otherwise arrays with automatic storage), then they cannot be moved, so this would not be an option anyway, but if the *large arrays* are dynamically allocated memory, *moving* will be much more efficient than copying. Note that in C++11 is the *presence* rather than the absence of `const` that can cause a performance penalty.

---

<sup>*</sup> This is not *100% true*, if the move assignment operator took the argument by *rvalue-reference* to `const`, then it could be moved. But none of the types in the standard library takes the argument this way, and I would not expect people to do it either (it would require `const_cast` inside the *move* operation (either constructor/assignment) and it just makes no sense: if you plan on *moving* (stealing) from it, why would you claim not to modify it??

Answer (score 2):

Since you're returning a temporary rvalue instance of type `T`, this statement doesn't do anything unless there are some global side-effects in the assignment operation, such as modifications to static variables that are data members of the type `T`, output to a terminal, etc.  Therefore depending on the type, and whether the assignment operator is a compiler default assignment operator, this entire operation may be safely elided in an optimization pass.  If there is a user-defined assignment operator for type `T`, then the assignment operation won't be elided, but as mentioned before, unless there are global side-effects, this won't do anything past the life-time of the statement's execution since you are not storing the value of `c` in an object that resides in a named and accessible memory location.

Keep in mind that if you do declare the return `T` type as `const`, and your operator method is not a `const` class method, you will disable certain types of operator chaining, as well as a host of other useful things, such as calling methods that have side-effects.  For instance:

```
(a+b).print(); //assuming print() is non-const method
```

or assuming  `operator+` is not a `const` class method,

```
d = (a+b) + c;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say don't ever implement `operator +` as member function. Just implement `operator +=` which is definitely not const. Then you provide a global function which takes care about `operator +`, I think this is the most common way to do it.

```
T& T::operator +=(const T& t)
{
    // add t to object ...
    return *this;
}

T operator +(T t1, const T& t2)
{
    t1 += t2
    return t1; // RVO will eliminate copy (or move constructor)
}
```

Comment: Good advice, but he's asking about constness of the return value, not whether or not the member function itself should be const. With regular functions, that would mean, "What is the performance difference between `T operator+(const T &, const T &);` and `const T operator+(const T &, const T&)` in terms of what the compiler can and cannot optimize?"