# Error while Overloading operator =

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Iv build a redBlack tree called layerOneTree and now I want to overload operator = for it but I don't know the syntax.

```
const layerOneTree& operator =(const layerOneTree &rhs); //in layerOneTree.h
```

the implementation:

```
layerOneTree& layerOneTree::operator= (const layerOneTree &rhs)//ERROR
{

if (this != &rhs) // if not self assignment
{
    reclaimMemory(m_root->rChildPtr); // clear its memory
    m_root->rChildPtr = theLeaf;
    m_root->rChildPtr = clone(rhs.m_root->rChildPtr);
}

return *this; // return current tree object
}
```

I know that there is a problem with `layerOneTree* layerOneTree::operator=` but I dont know how to fix it.

**Edit:** when I omit const in `const layerOneTree& operator =(const layerOneTree &rhs);` everything is ok, but Im trying to write my code like [this](http://larryvdh.com/blog/red-black-tree-implementation/). as you see in line 43, the definition is const. Why that code works and mine doesn't?

Comment: You forgot to show us the error message; but it's probably to do with the return type being `const` in the declaration but not the definition. It shouldn't be `const` in either.

Comment: You might need to do:

layerOneTree::layerOneTree& layerOneTree::operator= (const...)

It might also be the const thing.

These problems with function definitions are one of the things I find most annoying about C++. I wish they would fix it.

I've had this problem a lot of times. If you still can't fix it I'll break out some of my old c++ code and figure out what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @ScubaSteve What needs to be fixed?

Comment: I'm thinking it's where the return type is defined, like I said above.

Comment: @MikeSeymour When I delete `const` everything is ok, but im trying to implement my tree like [this](http://larryvdh.com/blog/red-black-tree-implementation/) and in like 43 of this code the definition is const!

Comment: Your declaration has const return type `const layerOneTree& ` while your definition has not `layerOneTree& `.

Comment: @MoNo: Make them either both `const` (as there) or neither `const`. It doesn't really matter, as long as they're both the same.

Comment: FWIW this is not a syntax error (the grammar of your code is fine -- syntax errors refer to grammatical errors that prevent parsing) but is rather an error with the semantic meaning of your code.  That is, it parses (so not a syntax error) but does not "make sense" to the compiler due to the contradiction between the two signatures, just as you can construct grammatically correct English arguments that contain self-contradictions.

Comment: I'm thinking your problem is here: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/const_correctness.html

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Im a mathematics student and this tree is part of a big program that computes edges of a special graph and everything is dependent on this tree! so I need it to be absolutely safe(that's why I'm implement it again myself). What is wrong with this code?

Comment: const in header but missing in implementation

Answer (score 1):

The definition and declaration of member functions have to match. The solution is to make both return the same type variable:

```
const layerOneTree& operator =(const layerOneTree &rhs); //in layerOneTree.h


const layerOneTree& layerOneTree::operator= (const layerOneTree &rhs)
{// Code
}
```

or:

```
layerOneTree& operator =(const layerOneTree &rhs); //in layerOneTree.h


layerOneTree& layerOneTree::operator= (const layerOneTree &rhs)
{// Code
}
```

I do prefer the second form because it's simpler and easier to understand.

The difference in behavior between the both may be found here: [Overloading operators : const vs non-const return type : any difference of performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919197/overloading-operators-const-vs-non-const-return-type-any-difference-of-perfo)

Comment: It does matter which one you use as they behave differently in chained assignment statements. The second one is generally considered the correct form.